# JQuery Plugins in VUE with Laravel Mix

Tags: jquery, vuejs2, laravel-5.4, vue-component, laravel-mix

In my `webpack.mix.js` I have something like this:

```
// vue components
mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js');

// scripts which I need
mix.scripts([
    'resources/assets/js/jquery-2.2.4.min.js',
    'resources/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js',
    'resources/assets/js/fastclick.js',
    'resources/assets/js/toastr.min.js',
    'resources/assets/js/select2.min.js',
    ...
], 'public/assets/js/scripts.js');

// styles which I need
mix.styles([
    "resources/assets/css/bootstrap-colorpicker.min.css",
    "resources/assets/css/bootstrap-select.min.css",
    "resources/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css",
    "resources/assets/css/select2.min.css",
    ...
], 'public/assets/css/styles.css');
```

And I can initialize, for example, a `select2` outside my vue components.

But when I trying to use this plugin (or any script of my `mix.scripts` block) I get the next error:

```
$(...).select2 is not a function
```

Okey, I search a little and I found a "solution", before the `export default{}` of my vue component I need to require the `select2` script:

```
 ...

import Vue from 'vue';

require('../select2.min.js');

export default{

...
```

And now it works inside and outside of my vue component: BUT I "import" my select2 plugin twice:

1. Inside my `public/assets/js/scripts.js` (which I need, because I use select2 and other plugins without a vue component)
2. And inside my `resources/assets/js/app.js` (when I run `npm run watch` or `npm run production` the compiler adds the requirement of my vue component to this script file)

So, my question is: **How can I make my components in VUE use the JQuery scripts coming from my `public/assets/js/scripts.js` file instead of having to require each of them within each vue component?**

I hope there is a way to do that

Answer (score 0):

As I know, the default `webpack.config.js` of Laravel mix include JQuery. So I commented the next line (271) from `webpack.config.js`:

```
/*
new webpack.ProvidePlugin(Mix.autoload || {
    jQuery: 'jquery',
    $: 'jquery',
    jquery: 'jquery'
}),
*/
```

And now when I show the content of JQuery `console.info($());` I see all the plugins.

But I think this its a bit dirty.

### There is any official way to do that?